# Wordpress div not showing on localhost version of site

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've got 2 versions of a site, a live testing version and a local version.

I'm currently working on the local version, using MAMP. The backend of both sites is identical, I've ensured that the admin of each site is exactly the same.

I'm trying to add images to the site via the **Edit Page** section, but the images aren't displaying.

I inspected the site to see any errors, none were found, however I came acrosss something interesting.

After comparing the html markup of the 2 site versions side by side, I noticed that my local version is missing the the div that displays images.

*Here is the div on the live version -*

[image]

*Here is the my local version, in which the div is not being shown -*
[image]

As you can see in the local version there is a `ul` instead of `div class="image-16-8`.

Here is the php file that is displaying these images

```
    <?php

function tbhHeroShortcode($atts)
{

    $values = shortcode_atts(array(
        'images' => '',
        'first-line' => '',
        'second-line' => '',
        'video' => '',
        'link' => '',
    ), $atts);
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="hero">
        <?
        $images = decode_shortcode_data($values['images']);
        if ($images): ?>
            <ul data-simple-slider>
                <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
                    <li>
                        <div class="image-16-8" style="background-image: url(<?= $image->url; ?>); "></div>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="hero-content">
            <div class="hero-content-first-line">
                <h1 class="header"><?= decode_shortcode_data($values['first-line']) ?></h1>

            </div>
            <h1 class="italic-header"><?= decode_shortcode_data($values['second-line']) ?></h1>

            <div class="hero-content-cta">
                <a class="hollow-button" href="<?= decode_shortcode_data($values['link']) ?>">Learn More</a>

            </div>

        </div>

        <?php if (count($images) > 1): ?>
            <div class="hero-controls">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left hero-controls__left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hero-controls__right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    $component = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $component;
}

add_shortcode('tbhHero', 'tbhHeroShortcode');
```

Does anyone have any idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well the ul is showing because it's right there in your php

```
<div class="hero">
    <?
    $images = decode_shortcode_data($values['images']);
    if ($images): ?>
        <ul data-simple-slider>
```

However, on your screenshot from the live version your hero div is different, it looks like this

```
<div class="hero" id>
```

The output you are seeing is not being generated by the same file, so either there is some browser/server caching going on and what you are seeing from the live site doesnt reflect the current state of your php, or somehow your php file updates are out of sync between your two environments.

Comment: What can I do to ensure my php files are in sync? I cleared all cached data but that didn't work.

Comment: Is caching enabled on the server? Content is not always generated from the php file every time, your server may have a cached copy of the html  which it is still outputting, the response headers should tell you. Try putting a ? at the end of your url, many servers won't output cached content if the request url contains a query

Comment: I disabled caching & putting a ? at the end of the url, I don't think this is a caching issue

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the difference between the two sites is in the "edit page" area of whatever page is serving as the home page.  I would expect that local version has a shortcode called [tbh-hero] on it with image listed, while the other one doesn't have any images listed or perhaps doesn't have a shortcode on it at all.  But, honestly, there are a lot of ways that that code could be implemented within the structure of a given theme.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite understanding. I just can't comprehend how the php can appear to be different, although I have the EXACT same file in my development environment

Comment: Not the php.  The "content" of the page.  The php you pasted in defines a shortcode.  Shortcodes are activated by the presence of an actual shortcode in the content area of the site.

Comment: Ok, you expect that the local version has a shortcode called [tbh-hero] on it with image listed, whilst the other doesn't. How can I check this? I'm currently comparing the page on both versions to ensure that everything is identical.

Comment: Just 'edit' whatever page is set to be the home page of each site.  From your screenshot it looks like that page will have an id of 195 on both sites,
 but the live site as it currently looks here http://tbhp.akeem.co/ has an id of 9, so I don't know which is right.